# a == b is false, but id(a) == id(b) is true?

Tags: python, object, methods, overriding

Ran into the following:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __str__(self):
...             return "some A()"
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def __str__(self):
...             return "some B()"
... 
>>> print A()
some A()
>>> print B()
some B()
>>> A.__str__ == B.__str__
False # seems reasonable, since each method is an object
>>> id(A.__str__)==id(B.__str__)
True # what?!
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 11):

As the string `id(A.__str__) == id(B.__str__)` is evaluated, `A.__str__` is created, its id taken, and then garbage collected.  Then `B.__str__` is created, and happens to end up at the exact same address that `A.__str__` was at earlier, so it gets (in CPython) the same id.

Try assigning `A.__str__` and `B.__str__` to temporary variables and you'll see something different:

```
>>> f = A.__str__
>>> g = B.__str__
>>> id(f) == id(g)
False
```

For a simpler example of this phenomenon, try:

```
>>> id(float('3.0')) == id(float('4.0'))
True
```

Comment: But then, why

>>> f = A.__str__

>>> id(f) == id(A.__str__)

False

Comment: `A.__str__` is created??? Not sure about this: it must be part of the metaclass that spawns all classes i.e. their basic "DNA".

Comment: @jldupont:  Python creates the unbound methods `A.__str__` and `B.__str__` at runtime.  http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm is a good reference for the underlying mechanisms.

Comment: @Krab:  There you've got two copies of `A.__str__` existing at the same time (apparently Python doesn't cache previously-created unbound methods in any way).  Any two distinct objects that exist simultaneously must have different ids.

Comment: hmmm... learning new things about Python every day! Thanks!  Not sure what are the implications of this behavior when it comes to using `id` for hashing objects though....

Comment: hmmm... can those be garbage collected that quick? I am still unconvinced about this explanation.

Comment: @jldupont, CPython is refcounted, so most things are garbage collected immediately. This is the correct explanation of what happens.

Comment: @jldupont:  It's easy to test the theory!  Try creating a subclass `myfloat` of float, and overriding `__new__` and `__del__` so that they log their calls appropriately.  Now watch the sequence of operations when you evaluate `id(myfloat(1.0)) == id(myfloat(2.0))`.
(Not that a call to `__del__` necessarily corresponds directly to garbage collection, though.)

Comment: @jldupont, Incidentally, you wouldn't usually use `id` to define a hash yourself. It's used for default for instances of classes you make, which is reliable and does not have descriptor subtlety. For a method (which is created on-the-fly), the hash depends on the underlying function (which is constant); there are not often times when this would make choosing a proper basis for a hash difficult.

Comment: @Mike Graham: tested the garbage collection behavior as hinted: I am convinced now. Thanks.

Comment: +1: for the entertaining discussion and pointing me to new learning material. Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

The following works:

```
>>> id(A.__str__.im_func) == id(A.__str__.im_func)
True
>>> id(B.__str__.im_func) == id(A.__str__.im_func)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of us here attracted by your title, to determine whether a method was overridden:

```
class A:
    def __str__(self):
        return "some A()"

    def strWasOverridden(self):
        return A.__str__ != self.__str__
```

Comment: Actually, no. This is always true, because an instance on a method is never equal to a method on a class.