# Python: Detect if a class method is redefined/overloaded from the C API

Tags: python

I am currently working on a C code where Python is embedded to setup the problem correctly. Therefore the user should derive his own problem from a Python class which defines the general structure. As minimal example I use

```
class testbase(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self._name = name
    def method1(self):
        pass
    def method2(self):
        pass
```

as base class. Now for each problem one should derive its own problem from this class like

```
class test(testbase):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self._name = name
    def method1(self):
        print self._name
```

where the `method2` is not defined by the user. Now I want to detect from the C API or at least in Python if the derived class provides `method2` or if it is used from the base class.

The first answers are not so precise as I though so if a have an instance of the test class

```
 T = test('test')
```

I want to know if `T.method2` is defined in `test` or inherited from `testbase`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Determine if method was overridden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319107/python-determine-if-method-was-overridden)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @ZachGates, I have used his idea to extend it to work with both classes and objects:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def parent_method(self):
        print('parent')

    @classmethod
    def parent_class_method(self):
        print('parent class method')

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def child_method(self):
        print('child')

    @classmethod
    def child_class_method(self):
        print('child class method')

def is_inherited_instance_method(test_object, method_name):
    """ 
    Gets the super object and looks up for it's method. 
    If the child has `method_name` atribute and parent doesn't,
    then method is new.
    """

    super_object = super(test_object.__class__, test_object)
    if hasattr(test_object, method_name) and not hasattr(super_object, method_name):
        # You can add extra checks, such as: callable() ...
        print('it is a new method: %s' % method_name)
    else:
        print('method is not new: %s' % method_name)

def is_inherited_class_method(test_cls, method_name):
    """ Does the same but only with Classes. """

    super_cls = super(test_cls, test_cls)
    if hasattr(test_cls, method_name) and not hasattr(super_cls, method_name):
        # You can add extra checks, such as: callable() ...
        print('it is a new class method: %s' % method_name)
    else:
        print('class method is not new: %s' % method_name)


parent = Parent()
child = Child()

is_inherited_instance_method(parent, 'parent_method')
is_inherited_instance_method(child, 'parent_method')
is_inherited_instance_method(child, 'child_method')

is_inherited_class_method(Parent, 'parent_class_method')
is_inherited_class_method(Child, 'parent_class_method')
is_inherited_class_method(Child, 'child_class_method')
```

And the output is:

```
it is a new method: parent_method
method is not new: parent_method
it is a new method: child_method

it is a new class method: parent_class_method
class method is not new: parent_class_method
it is a new class method: child_class_method
```

Comment: Nice check! Only thing worth mentioning is that it does not work with method overrides. The overriding method in the child is detected as NOT NEW. If I wanted to check if the method is used from the child or the base class I would expect a return of is NEW method in both cases called with child object and called with parent object.

Answer (score 1):

When specifying a subclass, all methods from the superclass are inherited.

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def bar(self):
        pass
```

Class `A` has a single method: `foo`. While class `B`, has two methods: a created `bar` method and an inherited `foo` method.

You can check if a method is inherited like this:

```
>>> def inherited(cls, method):
...     if hasattr(cls, method) and hasattr(super(cls, cls), method):
...         return A.foo == B.foo
...     else:
...         return False
...
>>> inherited(B, 'foo')
True
>>> inherited(B, 'bar')
False
```

Comment: I want to check if the method is an inherited one or not.

Comment: Edited to add that. @Grisu

Comment: The still works on the class not  on the instance of the class.